# WPF- DynamicGridCellStyle

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

i don't know how to set a text in a dynamic grid on top.It's alway only 'Center'.
This is my code snipped, see 'DESCRIPTION':

```
<Style x:Key="DynamicDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Typ}" Value="String">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}" 
                                     VerticalContentAlignment="Top"  BorderThickness="0" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="DESCRIPTION">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}" BorderThickness="0" Height="Auto" Background="WhiteSmoke" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                ToolTip="{Binding DataContext.UIString[], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, FallbackValue='Coole Sache'}" 
                                AcceptsReturn="True" IsTabStop="False"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Typ}" Value="DateTime">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{WPF:ValidatedBinding Value}" SelectedDateFormat="Short" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
```

VerticalContentAlignment="Top" has no affect. Didn' find anything on the web.
Many thanks for help.

Greetings
Michael

Comment: Try put your textbox in a grid and set verticalalignment on the textbox

Comment: as you can see in my code i use dynamicdatagridcell.

Comment: See where you have textbox? Within each controltemplate and around each textbox. Grid. Get it?

Comment: VerticalAligment Value="top" has also to be defined in DynamicDataGridLabelStyle. Now it works. thx for input